# "Bury vs. Berry" The Proper Pronunciation Edition

Tags: etymology, american-english, pronunciation

In America growing up in the Midwest, I've always heard people pronounce the word "bury" as if it were pronounced sounding the same as the word "berry".

Ever since I've noticed this many years back I've always pronounced the word "bury" as it's spelled and I think it should be pronounced but it seems no one else pronounces this word like I do.

If a man needs to bury some berries, it'd sound strange if you pronounce both words that sound the same with the "air" instead of "ur" sound.

- [Listen to this "bury" for the way I pronounce it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fh3eCn4ZZas)

### Question(s)

*I apologize for the correlated sub-questions*

I'm curious what the history is behind this word and it's pronunciation in America and why so many people pronounce it sounding a different way than I do based on its spelling?

- Maybe pronouncing "bury" that sounds like someone is saying "berry" is appropriate or proper and I say it incorrectly assuming that's the correct way to pronounce it?

Comment: I tend to pronounce "bury" with a touch of the U sound, but I'm guessing it's usually indistinguishable from "berry".  Saying them, the difference I note is that "berry" puts a smile on my face, whereas "bury" makes me frown.  But this makes very little difference in pronunciation.  (US Midwest)

Comment: Spelling and pronunciation only correlate in English,  and often not well, eg, *colonel*, *victuals*.  What you call "improper" is probably "proper" to others. See also [North American English Dialects](http://aschmann.net/AmEng/).

Comment: Growing up in the east, "bury" and "berry" are identical for me too.  I have never heard anyone pronounce "bury" as "burr-ee".

Comment: A Northern Irish accent might pronounce *bury* as "burry". But then it would pronounce *berry* the same way. (What surprises me about this question is: "I do X but no-one else does. Why are they all wrong when I've decided I'm right?" I wonder if there's a better way to ask the question.)

Comment: Everyone else is a robot except for you. Any semblance to humanity they may have is purely for entertainment value (the robots')

Comment: I'd be ***very*** surprised to learn that there's an English dialect (as opposed to OP's misguided [idiolect](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/idiolect)) where ***berry*** and ***very*** aren't homophones.

Comment: If you live in Bury, England, you're likely to pronounce it "Burry" rather then "Berry" - I used to work there and had to get out of the habit of saying "Berry".

Comment: Here's a clip of a Midwestern speaker reading a text, with links to other English accents or dialects http://accent.gmu.edu/browse_language.php?function=detail&speakerid=550

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous: First, _burr-ee_ is not the way anybody I've ever heard pronounces _bury_; it's sposta be a homophone for _berry_ and rhyme with _very_, as noted. Second, pronunciation comes **first**, and spelling -- if any -- comes later. Third, English spelling doesn't represent correct English pronunciation; it's a very good spelling system for Middle English, last spoken around 1550. Modern English, not so much. So you have to give up the idea that spelling is primary; spelling is actually just arbitrary, and a pain to remember. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Mike C That would be the Bury of black pudding fame rather than the one of Greene King Brewery fame.

Comment: @JohnLawler,  I grew up on the US east coast.  I've heard it both ways, rhyming with "very" and "furry".  Interestingly, the recordings [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/bury) sound like they rhyme with very for UK, and Barry for US.

Comment: In most of the US (excepting the NE coast), _Barry_ and _very_ rhyme. In the NE, some people distinguish _Mary_ /meri/, _merry_ /mɛri/, and _marry_ /mæri/. But in the rest of the country, they're all identical and rhyme with _very_.

Comment: There are references and examples all over the place but nothing where I can conclusively say this is right, or this is right, or both are right and it doesn't matter how you say it.

Comment: US NE coast: Mary rhymes with contrary (as in the nursery rhyme); similar to mare (a horse).  Merry rhymes with very or berry.  Marry rhymes with Larry.  Barry also rhymes with Larry; the "a" sounds similar to Sally.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, you're right, the inhabitants of black-pudding Bury pronounce it "Burry", Bury-St-Edmonds is entirely different.

Comment: As it’s spelled?? So it should sound like ***fury***??

Comment: @Jim Not like ``/ˈbyo͝orē`` but like ``/ˈbərē/`` but that's a good point though, ha!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is based on a few misconceptions.

"Correct" is not a clearly defined concept for pronunciation. But so far as we can speak of "correct pronunciation" of English words, it's definitely not a matter of pronouncing things "as they are spelled". People generally consider it appropriate to use pronunciations that are widely used and not associated with particular stigmatized social groups, like lower-class speakers or speakers of stigmatized minority dialects.

There are many words that have a spelling that doesn't correspond to any widely used pronunciation. For example, the word *friend* is spelled with "ie", like the word *fiend*, but /friːnd/ ("freend") is not a widely used pronunciation in modern English (I have no idea if this pronunciation may exist in some obscure dialect), so it is not considered correct.  The correct pronunciation of *friend* is instead considered to be /frɛnd/ ("frend"). So we can see that the idea of "correct pronunciation" cannot be based on spelling alone. There are other factors influencing what is considered "correct".

The pronunciation that would be expected for "bury" if it had a completely regular spelling would actually be /bjʊəri/, because there is only one R after the U (compare *fury, jury* and *bureau*).

But "bury" doesn't have a completely regular spelling. Rather, the spelling is based on weird details of its historical development. See the following note from the [Etymonline entry for "bury"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bury):

> The Old English -*y*- was a short "oo" sound, like modern French -*u*-. Under normal circumstances it transformed into Modern English -*i*- (in **bridge, kiss, listen, sister**, etc.), but in bury and a few other words (**merry, knell**) it retained a Kentish change to "e" that took place in the late Old English period. In the West Midlands, meanwhile, the Old English *-y-* sound persisted, slightly modified over time, giving the standard modern pronunciation of **blush, much, church**.

The people in the comments who say they have heard *bury* pronounced to rhyme with *furry* in an American accent may have heard someone with the "[Merry–Murray merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Merry.E2.80.93Murray_merger)". A speaker with this accent would also rhyme *berry* and *ferry* with *furry*.

Comment: Wow.... holy cow.... and over a year later, we have a technically correct answer.... at least I think but that is a lot of good detail for sure. While I don't believe I'm of the [Philadelphia English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia_English) dialect, for some reason for this particular word I pronounce it that way still such as "bury" as in "hurry" and no one seems to ever try to correct me but when I hear others say it as "berry" pronunciation it always sticks out to me for some reason. I suppose that's a personal thing but thank you very much regardless for your awesome answer.

Comment: Something else that is funny I've noticed with people from Gary Indiana in particular from those I've heard talk with certain words such as "there" some people pronounce it like "thur" but the only people I've heard personally talk like that have been from the Gary Indiana area.... lol

Comment: @Facebook: Interesting. With a word like "there", it might be hard to tell if the change in the pronunciation of the vowel is based on a generally applicable sound change, or a reduction that applies mainly to that one word.

Comment: Personally I rhyme it with “jury”, and I pronounce “Merry” and “Murray” to rhyme with “hairy” and “flurry”. I’m in Massachusetts, not sure if I’m just using a spelling pronunciation or if I got that pronunciation from people around me.